# Why script not stop symbol with keyCode 69?

Tags: jquery, keyup

When i test my simple code, i get one problem - script should blocked symbols besides numbers, but he not blocked symbol **e** with keyCode 69.

Code:

```
$('#test').on('keyup', function(e) {
  console.log(e.keyCode);
  if( !((e.keyCode >=48 && e.keyCode <=57) || (e.keyCode >=96 && e.keyCode <=105) || e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) ){
    return false;
  }
});
```

Problem keyCode - 69. Why script not stop symbol **e** (keyCode 69) and how to solve a problem?

Comment: can you say - why votedown?

Comment: you should try `keypress`-event

Comment: @JohnnyAW keyup stop other symbols too, you can test

Comment: can you chek with the debugger, if you actually hit your condition?

Comment: @JohnnyAW keypress work (for keyup was other keyCode), thanks

Comment: @JohnnyAW can you post answer, that i can close question ?

Comment: Did you mean to ask about keyCode 96 rather than 69?

Comment: @Ouroborus if use `keyup` than keyCode will be 69

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#test').on('keypress', function(e) {
  if( !(e.which >=48 && e.which <=57) ){
    return false;
  }
});
```

P.S.: bad night, bad question... thanks @JohnnyAW..